# Is there a way to add expandable thumbnails to an MS Word document?

Tags: images, microsoft-word-2007, thumbnails

I want to add pictures and screenshots of a web page to a document in Microsoft Word 2007. The problem is, when I add them to my document, they occupy a lot of space and don't leave much room for text.

Is there any way that they can be replaced with thumbnails, which, when clicked, cause the original pictures to expand/pop-outs? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how far you want to go to achieve this, you could put your screenshots into separate documents and put those documents into your main Word file. Embedded documents will open in a new instance of Word when double-clicked.

Making the embedded document look good can be quite challenging though. The best way I found was to try to crop it by placing it inside a table with a single cell.

Word simply wasn't made for this.